# How to float right/pull right for text-muted class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make the text-muted class float right.

Float right, pull right. Not working

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th class="card-header" colspan="2"></th>
     </tr>
     <tr colspan="2">
        <td style="display: flex;">
           <strong>Username:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;A Comment
           <small class="form-text text-muted">5 mins ago</small>
           <br/>
        </td> 
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The text-muted float right or pull right for better view.

Comment: remove display: flex from td and add float-right to the muted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are using **display: flex** in **parent element** and **float** is not working properly with it. There are 2 option to resolve your issue.

**Without Flex Option 1:**

Remove **display: flex** from parent element and add **float-right** class with **text-muted** class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th class="card-header" colspan="2"></th>
     </tr>
     <tr colspan="2">
        <td>
           <strong>Username:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;A Comment
           <small class="form-text text-muted float-right">5 mins ago</small>
           <br/>
        </td> 
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**With Flex Option 2:**

Using **display: flex** and **justify-content: space-between** and update minor HTML structure.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th class="card-header" colspan="2"></th>
     </tr>
     <tr colspan="2">
        <td class="d-flex justify-content-between">
           <div>
            <strong>Username:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;A Comment
           </div>
           <small class="form-text text-muted">5 mins ago</small>
        </td> 
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```